# Mathematical Statistics : Transformation in a sequence of real random variable

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to solve this problem : 
Let $(X_k)_{k \in N^*}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. real random variables distributed as a Bernoulli of parameter $p \in (0,1)$. For each $k \in N^*$, we set $Y_k = X_k X_{k+1}$.

1. Find the distribution of $Y_k$, its expectation and variance.
2. Compute $Cov(Y_k,Y_{k+1})$ for $ i \in N^*$ (Distinguish 2 cases: $i=1$ and $i>1$)

So I have tried : 
$P(Y_k =y) =P(X_k X_{k+1} = y) $ and then I'm stuck.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh So I tried P(Yk=y) = P(Xk*X_k+1 = y) and then stuck.

Comment: I have edited my answer to mention the covariance, since it is more complex than I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{B_1,B_2,\dots,B_n\}$ be a collection of independent Bernoulli random variables each with parameter $p$. Then the product $\prod_{i=1}^n B_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p^n$.

Fr each $k\in N^*$, $Y_k=X_kX_{k+1}$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p^2$. Its expected value is $E[Y_k]=p^2$ and its variance is $\text{var}(Y_k)=p^2(1-p^2)$.

To calculate the covariance between $Y_k$ and $Y_{k+1}$ use the formula
$$\text{cov}(Y_k,Y_{k+1})=E[Y_kY_{k+1}]-E[Y_k]E[Y_{k+1}]$$
To calculate the expected value of $Y_kY_{k+1}$ expand the product and use the fact that any Bernoulli random variable $X$ and its square $X^2$ have identical distribution.
$$Y_kY_{k+1}=X_k(X_{k+1})^2X_{k+2}=X_kX_{k+1}X_{k+2}$$
From Lemma 1 we have  $E[X_kX_{k+1}X_{k+2}]=p^3$. And $E[Y_k]=E[Y_{k+1}]=p^2$. Therefore:
$$\text{cov}(Y_k,Y_{k+1})=p^3-p^4$$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- $Y_k$ takes only two values, what distribution does it follow? What is the probability that it takes value $1$?
- \begin{align}Cov(Y_k, Y_{k+1})&=E(Y_kY_{k+1})-E(Y_k)E(Y_{k+1})\\
  &=E(X_kX_{k+1}^2X_{k+2})-E(Y_k)E(Y_{k+1})\end{align}